# CircularBuffer with template is ambiguous error on Keil MDK5?

Tags: c++, templates, keil, ambiguous, mbed

I have built a mbed project with online ARMCC compiler, which has no complaints at all. After exporting projects to offline Keil MDK5. I got following complaints. Please advice if anyone knows how to remove/correct such issue.

```
SerialInterfaceProtocol/SerialInterfaceProtocol.h(16): error:  #266: "CircularBuffer" is ambiguous
  typedef CircularBuffer<uint8_t> SerialBuffer_t;

AlohaTransceiver/AlohaTransceiver.h(178): error:  #266: "CircularBuffer" is ambiguous
  CircularBuffer<AlohaFrame *> AlohaTxQueue;

AlohaTransceiver/AlohaTransceiver.cpp(44): error:  #266: "CircularBuffer" is ambiguous
  CircularBuffer<AlohaFrame *> AlohaRxQueue(10);

main.cpp(12): error:  #266: "CircularBuffer" is ambiguous
  CircularBuffer<uint8_t> SerialInputBuffer(128);

main.cpp(13): error:  #266: "CircularBuffer" is ambiguous
  CircularBuffer<uint8_t> SerialOutputBuffer(128);
```

I know CircularBuffer seems ambiguous if it has differenet types, but CircularBuffer is defined as a template, which should be used for different types? And online compiler passed, but MDK5 didn't, is there any compiler options should be enabled ?

The CircularBuffer is defined in RingBuffer.h

```
#ifndef RINGBUFFER_H_
#define RINGBUFFER_H_

#define DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_SZ 64

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <typename T>
class CircularBuffer
{
private:
    const size_t buffer_size;
    size_t read_ptr;
    size_t write_ptr;
    size_t count;

    // mutex lock
    bool mux; 

    // overflow
    bool is_over_flow;

    // container
    T *data;


public:
    CircularBuffer(const size_t size=DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_SZ);
    ~CircularBuffer();

    // psudo mutex
    bool isLocked();
    void lock();
    void unlock();

    // enqueue and dequeue
    void enqueue(T in);
    T dequeue();

    // pointer operation
    size_t getReadPtr();
    size_t getWritePtr();
    size_t getCounter();

    // overflow
    bool getOverFlow();
    void clearOverFlow();

    // operation
    T first();
    T last();

    // random access
    T operator[](size_t idx);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Does this compiler even support templates?

Comment: Although there is no official documents to support, template works in other projects well with Keil MDK5. So, I guess yes.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that template is supported by Keil MDK5, by exporting another [template based demo project called MyBuffer](https://developer.mbed.org/users/sam_grove/code/Buffer/). And the problematic project is called [RingBuffer](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/ENEL400/code/RingBuffer/) and its dependent projects are called [LoRaBaseStation](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/ENEL400/code/LoRaBaseStation/) and [LoRaTerminal](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/ENEL400/code/LoRaTerminal/). Both projects can be built online, failed with Keil MDK5. So, something wrong in the code.

Comment: Now I am trying to migrate MyBuffer and Ringbuffer templates to find out why and where to complaint. Otherwise, I have to downgrade to static type ringbuffer implementations with uint8_t and pointers.

Comment: Well, Since most of the RingBuffers are identical in features, just push/pop/isAvaiable and so on. I copied another RingBuffer library into the project, and it works ! Then I realized such complains may has something to do with mbed/platform/CircularBuffer.h after searching the whole project.

The mbed has its own CircularBuffer already in the hardware platform, and I included another RingBuffer library, which declared itself as CircularBuffer, that may be the reason why the build system throw out complains, because it has two similiar CircularBuffer in same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two **CircularBuffer** in the project, one is in mbed OS, the other is in user code. Merge them, or rename one of them.